# jQuery code to change an IMG on load of a div

Tags: jquery, image, tabs, swap, flowplayer

I am using Flowplayer tabs (http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.html) and after some research it seems that you can't have one set of tabs to change the content of two different panels.

On my page is a large banner image, below this are the tabs, and below this is the content container. Clicking a tab changes between different divs in the content container. How can I get the banner image, which is outside the content container, to change depending on what tab has been selected? Am I right in thinking that each tab can have some jQuery code immediately after its div tag begins, which changes the banner image as soon as the div loads?

Many thanks, I'm still getting my head around jQuery so hopefully this is something basic..!

Comment: I would clarify by saying each tab can have some jQuery associated with it, but the code would not physically exist right after the div. Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded an example here: http://www.adaptdesign.com/misc/cta/services.html thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
   $("#example").tabs(".panes > div", {
      onClick : function(e, index) { 
            switch(index) {
              case 1:
                   // first tab 
                   $('#banner-img').attr('src', 'images/img1.png');
                   break;
                  case 2:
                   //second tab
                   $('#banner-img').attr('src', 'images/img2.png');
                   break; 
           }
     }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, how exactly would the two 'cases' become linked to the tabs? I have uploaded the code I am working with to http://www.adaptdesign.com/misc/cta/services.html .

Comment: the `onClick` event fires everytime a tab is clicked (see [flowplayer tabs doc](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html)) and the second argument is the index of the tab clicked. The `switch` will alter the image based on which tab index is passed over.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I've uploaded this code onto services.html on the above link, would you mind taking a quick look? Any further input would be most appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working with Firebug for a second or two, I'll keep playing around, but something I'm curious about is that there are links across the website that link to particular tabs on this Services page... I'm guessing the code you have kindly helped me with won't load the new banners because your code loads the banners using an 'onClick' event, thus why I wondered if any code can be executed to change the banners as the matching DIV appears in the content container? Any ideas on this? If not, what you posted is going to be the best I can do. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Out of desperacy I have gone for a CSS solution - each banner is placed in its corresponding tab and is absolutely positioned where it needs to be. Seems to work in every browser I've tested in besides IE6, so that'll do! Thanks for your help, after seeing the jQuery solution working in Firebug once very quickly I haven't been able to get it working since unfortunately.